# Can I completely remove Gnome and leave xmonad?

Tags: gnome, uninstall, window-manager, xmonad

I've installed xmonad. I'm trilled with it. I can now use it as my one and only WM. I'm just wondering is it going to work without problems if I totally remove Gnome.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: It probably depends on how you define "Gnome".  The libraries provided by Gnome are used by many applications, so you couldn't completely remove Gnome without also removing many other applications.  Removing components like the panel, etc is possible, but you'd probably end up removing the `ubuntu-desktop` package as a side effect.  That in turn could lead to new desktop components not being installed when you upgrade distros (but that might be what you want anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a hassle, but i would re-install the whole system without X (using the  the [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) version of Ubuntu), and then perform a clean install of Xorg and XMonad:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install xorg xinit`
`sudo apt-get install xmonad`

... plus all the other small stuff you need; mail client, web browser,

This way you will get a clean and lightweight system. Typing startx will start X
X wont start automatically during boot, you'll have to configure that.

A clean installation like this will not have some of the fancy tools included in a vanilla ubuntu workstation, like *Network Manager*. See it as a chance to learn Ubuntu/linux from the inside.

Use `xset` and `xterm` to configure screensaver/powersave, use `xrand` to set monitor resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove Gnome (desktop environment) to install xmonad (window manager), a window manager need a desktop environment to run on it, but if you want to install xmonad as a window manager you should use it on Xfce or LXDE both are desktop environments.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Xmonad is capable of running without a desktop environment. Much like Openbox does.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install Xmonad during a Gnome session than logout and select Xmonad from the login menu.